# bxslider v4 image anchor tag not working in chrome but working in mozila

Tags: bxslider

We are using bxslider for product image slider. By default it comes with images, but without anchor links on the images. We needed to add these links to the images.

It's working in Mozilla for me, but the links don't work in chrome.

Anybody faced this same issue ever? How can I get the links to work in Chrome?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your reply .Please check the link http://www.allindiatharky.com/landing/landing.html   Here link is added on apple images to redirect to google.com but  it's not working . In mozilla it's working . in chrome it's not working . can you please help ? Thank you